# How to use transition/animation when changing visibility with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, visibility

I want the dropdown to fade in and out onclick using JavaScript but now it´s just appearing and disapearing quickly.

```js
    function toggleDropdown() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    
        if (x.style.visibility === "visible") {
          x.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
          x.style.visibility = "visible";
      
        }
      }
```

```css
 #myDropdown{
           visibility: hidden;
           // -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
           // animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
           transition: visibility 1s linear 300ms, visibility 300ms;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <button onclick="toggleDropdown()">Choose connection</button>
          <div id="myDropdown">
            <img src="images/searchicon.png" alt="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="">
            <a href="">Base</a>
            <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Animate the opacity instead of the visibility

Comment: `"toggleDropdown()` <<< why is here missing a `"`

Comment: `id=" myDropdown "` !== `id="myDropdown"`

Comment: Sorry my bad, accidentally removed  the ". But  I can´t find the error about spaces in the id-name

Comment: visibility can't be animated but opacity can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: fix visibility

```js
function toggleDropdown() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  if (x.style.opacity === "1") {
    x.style.opacity = "0";
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } 
  else {
    x.style.opacity = "1";
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```css
#dropdown {
  height:20px;
}
#myDropdown {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0.3s linear,opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <!-- <a href="#">Open Menu</a> -->
    <button onclick="toggleDropdown()">Choose connection</button>
    <div id="myDropdown">
      <img src="images/searchicon.png" alt="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="">
      <a href="">Base</a>
      <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS transition only works on ordinal/calculable properties
Instead of `visibility`, you should use `opacity`
css

```
 #myDropdown{
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 1s linear 300ms, opacity 300ms;
 }
```

js

```
 function toggleDropdown() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myDropdown");

     if (x.style.opacity === "1") {
         x.style.opacity = "0";
     } 
     else {
         x.style.opacity = "1";
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

- **Use [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)** to store the target element's selector (ID) and the className to toggle
  i.e: `data-toggle="#myDropdown:is-visible"`
- **Use [classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** to toggle that class
- Define inside your CSS the desired transition
- PS: **don't use inline JS** `on*` handlers - same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. JS should be in one place only, and that's your `script`.
- **Don't create functions that do one thing only** (I.e toggle a visibility state for one element only) - instead create a function that you can reuse for a myriad of elements:

```js
const toggle = (ev) => {
  const EL_btn = ev.currentTarget;
  const [target, className] = EL_btn.dataset.toggle.split(":");
  const EL_target = document.querySelector(target);
  EL_target.classList.toggle(className);
};

const ELS_toggle = document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle]");
ELS_toggle.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", toggle));
```

```css
.is-invisible {
  transition: 0.6s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button data-toggle="#myDropdown:is-visible">TOGGLE</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="is-invisible">ANY CONTENT YOU WANT TO SHOW</div>
```